# robot_localization publishing to tf incorrectly

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, base-link, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have left the robot_localization odom_frame parameter with value "odom" and base_link_frame to "base_link" defaults. The tf tree, while running robot_localization and the robot driver ca_driver with publish_tf set to "false". Looks like this (apparently I can't upload a file with less than 5 points):
odom floating.
base_footprint ---> base_link (broadcaster /ekf_localization)
base_link --> right_wheel link (broadcaster /robot_state_publisher)
base_link --> left_wheel link (broadcaster /robot_state_publisher) ....

why is ekf_localization broadcasting base_footprint --> base_link ? and leaving odom floating? (not connected to anything)
I can't even find base_footprint anywhere in the robot_localization parameter list. It is part of the robot description.
Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.

Edit

Adding image of original tf tree
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241514/robot_localization-publishing-to-tf-incorrectly/) by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-10**:
I've bumped your karma; you should be able to post images now.

**Comment by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) on 2016-08-11**:
Thank you. I've posted image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

by changing the `base_link_frame` parameter value from `base_link` to `base_footprint` I was able to connect the `odom` frame to `base_footprint`. I can now run the robot and visualize the `ekf_localization` output in RViz.
Interestingly, the `base_footprint` to `base_link` transform is now broadcast by `/robot_state_publisher`

---

Originally posted by [ras_cal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27002/ras_cal/) with karma: 40 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0